# Is IDLE a console?

Tags: pip, console, python-idle

I want to check whether pip is installed, but I don't know how to do that.
I tried typing pip into IDLE:

```
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
>>> pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    pip
NameError: name 'pip' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: This is a console for the Python prompt. What you are seeing is the Python [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) in which you are supposed to type in valid Python syntax. But you are meant to type in `pip` outside of this REPL, maybe in a bash shell or at the Windows command prompt or in a Powershell session.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use IDLE to run pip. Check if you have pip installed by opening up command prompt and typing `pip help` or `pip --version` If you get an error it's obviously not installed.

To update pip, enter `python -m pip install -U pip`.